# Elementary "bugs" in computer algebra systems?

Tags: education, computer-algebra-systems

There's a discussion of bugs in CAS's [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors), but these are technical errors of interest mainly to the professional mathematician.  I am more interested in simple errors which might arise in the use of CAS for undergraduate teaching.  For example, if we were asked to compute

$$\int x(1+x)^{19}\,dx$$

say, we would use integration by parts and end up with

$$\frac{1}{20}x(1+x)^{20}-\frac{1}{420}(1+x)^{21}+C$$

which is neat, and clearly easily generalizable to any power.  However, your CAS, given this problem, is likely to think: "Aha!  products of powers of polynomials!", expand the integrand into powers of $x$ and integrate the result term by term.  The result is not formally *wrong*, but it *is* confusing, and from the point of view of elementary teaching, useless.

Does anybody know of other examples where a CAS (or CAS calculator like the TI-Nspire, the Casio ClassPad, or the HP Prime), gives an answer which is either wrong, or in a form which is useless?

Comment: What about writing $x(1+x)^{19} = (1+x)^{20} - (1+x)^{19}$, which leads to the primitive $$\frac{1}{21} (1+x)^{21} - \frac{1}{20}(1+x)^{20} + C$$ with less pain and opportunities for error than integrating by parts?

Comment: Dear Daniel Fischer - the reason I didn't mention that method is that, while clearly less prone to error, it requires an algebraic sense not likely to be seen in, at least, my own students!

Answer (score 5):

Pick your favorite expression that is zero but not easily simplified to zero by the CAS. Then divide by this zero and deduce all kinds of absurdities.

Another place a CAS go wrong is properly dealing with branch cuts, and keeping track of domains of validity for various expressions.

These and other problems have been discussed in the literature. A good place to find such information is to browse the web pages of leading researchers, and conference proceedings (ISSAC,SYMSAC,Sigsam,Eurosam, etc). For example, see [Richard Fateman's papers](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/algebra.html), e.g. his [33 page critique of Mathematica,](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/mma.review.pdf) and [Why Computer Algebra Systems Can't Solve Simple Equations](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/y=z2w.pdf) and [Branch Cuts in Computer Algebra,](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/ding.ps) etc.